# Google server-side Sign-in using grantOffliceAccess

Tags: node.js, angular, google-api, google-api-nodejs-client

I'm not sure if this is possible using the current Node.js client but i have been trying to implement the following server-side sign-in flow as stated here - https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/server-side-flow but using node instead of Java/Python.

I have it successfully granting offline access, generating a code and sending it to my web server but when i try to get a token using the code i always get a `unauthorized_client` error.

I'm asking here as i wasn't sure if this is flow is actually achievable using the node version of the api. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Client side (TypeScript - Angular 5+):

```
onGrantAccess() {
  gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().grantOfflineAccess({
    scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly'
  }).then((response) => {
    this.ngZone.run(() => {
      console.log(response)
      this.saveAuthCode(response["code"])
    })
  });
}

saveAuthCode(code) {
  let headers = new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
  this.http.post("http://localhost:3000/gapi/auth/storecode", { code: code }, { headers: headers }).subscribe((response) => {
    console.log(response)
  })
}
```

Server side (Node.js - Express:

```
async function authorize(authCode, res) {
   const data = await fs.readJson('./routes/google/client_secrets.json')
   const oauth2Client = new OAuth2Client(
     data["client_id"],
     data["client_secret"],
     ''
   );
   oauth2Client.getToken(authCode, function (err, tokens) {
        if (!err) {
            oauth2Client.setCredentials(tokens);
            console.log(tokens);
        }
        else{
            console.log("Error "+err);
        }
    });

   return oauth2Client
}

router.post('/', async (req, res, next) => {
  const {code} = req.body
  console.log(code)
  oauth2Client = await authorize(code, res)
});
```